# How to set a custom page in layouts folder as SharePoint Site HomePage

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Redirect default.aspx or change default landing to page in _layouts folder?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31804/redirect-default-aspx-or-change-default-landing-to-page-in-layouts-folder)

I want to set custom page which resides in "_layouts/CustomPages/Home.aspx" as HomePage for the sharepoint site. When i deploy the feature containing the below code. The solution is getting deployed but the homepage is not set the same instead default.aspx which the default home page for a site is set as home page. How to achieve my requirement. Where i am going wrong?.

My code on FeatureDeactivating event is as follows

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            SPSite site = (SPSite)properties.Feature.Parent;

            SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            web.MasterUrl = web.ServerRelativeUrl + "_catalogs/masterpage/v4.master";
            web.CustomMasterUrl = web.ServerRelativeUrl + "_catalogs/masterpage/v4.master";                
            SPFolder rootFolder = web.RootFolder;
            rootFolder.WelcomePage = "default.aspx";
            rootFolder.Update();
            web.Update();
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

        });
```

My code on FeatureActivated event is as follows

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            SPSite site = (SPSite)properties.Feature.Parent;

            SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            web.MasterUrl = web.ServerRelativeUrl + "_catalogs/masterpage/CRMT/blue.master";
            web.CustomMasterUrl = web.ServerRelativeUrl + "_catalogs/masterpage/CRMT/blue.master";
            //Make custom landing Page as Site Home Page             
            SPFolder rootFolder = web.RootFolder;
            rootFolder.WelcomePage = "_Layouts/CustomPages/Home.aspx"; //custom landing page    
            rootFolder.Update();
            web.Update();
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

        });
```

Comment: Also, this one: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31804/redirect-default-aspx-or-change-default-landing-to-page-in-layouts-folder