# How to deploy an application page and set it as introduction/startup page?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-server

I have a Powershell script that creates a web app and a (root) site collection (Sharepoint 2010).

In VS2012 I want to deploy an application page that will be a introduction/startup page.

How can be done (as best practice) ?

(should I create an aspx page and create a module??)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a module which which will deploy the page to a library. A site collection feature will then change the welcome page to the newly added page. See following code

```
using (SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite("http://MyServer/sites/MyWikiSite"))
{
    SPWeb oWebsite = oSiteCollection.OpenWeb();
    SPFolder oFolder = oWebsite.RootFolder; 
    oFolder.WelcomePage = "My Wiki Library/MyWelcome.aspx";
    oFolder.Update();
    oWebsite.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I have done this in the feature activation. Note that this is an application page (not a site page). I have tested it, and it doesn't work...

Comment: You cannot set application page as the welcome page. However, this link seems to have a workaround http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31804/redirect-default-aspx-or-change-default-landing-to-page-in-layouts-folder